# Joining three tables on two IDs

Tags: sql, join, multiple-tables

I have this exercise for an application and I can't really check if I'm doing it right because I'm a beginner and I don't how to make my own database.

These are the given data:

Table 1: Company

| Company_ID | Name | Desc | Location | Ticker |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | An.. | US | AB |
| 2 | EFG | An.. | US | EF |
| 3 | HIJ | An.. | EU | HI |

Table 2: Others

| Company_ID | Ratings | Issue | BUD_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | An... | US |
| 2 | EFG | An... | US |
| 3 | HIJ | An... | EU |

Table 3: Sectors

| Company_ID | Sector | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Electronic |  |
| 2 | Industrial | 000111 |
| 3 | Manufacturing | 222333 |

Here's what I've written: I need to extract the name, description, location, issue, and BUD_ID  based on company id's 2 and 3

```
SELECT c.Company_ID, c.Name, c.Description, c.Location, cxi.Issue, cxi.BUD_ID
FROM Companies as c
JOIN Others as cxi
ON c.Company_ID = cxi.Company_ID
JOIN Sectors as csx
ON c.Company_ID = csx.Company_ID
WHERE c.Company_ID = '2'
AND c.Company_ID = '3';
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: share expected output

Comment: You're probably thinking of **WHERE c.Company_ID = '2' OR c.Company_ID = '3';**. You can't have both ID's on the same row.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
SELECT c.Company_ID, c.Name, c.Description, c.Location, cxi.Issue, cxi.BUD_ID
FROM Companies as c
JOIN Others as cxi
ON c.Company_ID = cxi.Company_ID
JOIN Sectors as csx
ON c.Company_ID = csx.Company_ID
WHERE c.Company_ID = '2'
AND c.Company_ID = '3';
```

to:

```
SELECT c.Company_ID, c.Name, c.Description, c.Location, cxi.Issue, cxi.BUD_ID
FROM Companies as c
JOIN Others as cxi
ON c.Company_ID = cxi.Company_ID
JOIN Sectors as csx
ON c.Company_ID = csx.Company_ID
WHERE c.Company_ID = '2'
OR c.Company_ID = '3';
```

You cannot have ID 2 and 3 on the same row. If you want to get data for both use the OR rather than AND.